# How to pick up timespec_add_safe() for a Linux C++ application

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, compilation

Folks,
Anyone know what/how I can include the appropriate header in order to pick up timespec_add_safe() for a Linux C++ application? Or maybe which library to link to in order to extern to timespec_add_safe()? My environment is kernel version 3.11.0-14-generic within Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander, and I am already linking my application with -lrt.

Note that my unfruitful investigations have indicated that timespec_add_safe() is coming from time.h, which in my environment is: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-13/include/linux/time.h  Also, note that my application is already including the standard time.h (/usr/include/time.h) for struct timespec and other "time" definitions. Further, I observe that the kernel has its own time.h (of course lacking the declaration for timespec_add_safe()) in /usr/include/linux/time.h. So, an extension of my question is, what are the differences/caveats between these inlude directories:

```
/usr/include                        - standard headers?
/usr/include/linux                  - kernel headers?
/usr/src/linux-headers-xxx/include  - what exactly is this? when/how to use?
```

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: always include the user space headers.

Comment: timespec_add_safe is *in the kernel* (`grep timespec_add_safe /proc/kallsyms` should reveal this), not in any userland code, so even if you `#include` a file with the declaration, the definition is not present, so it will not link. The implementation is trivial. You could even cadge it from `time.c` in the linux kernel.

Comment: Thanks @Petesh. That worked. I simply cadged the implementation from the kernel.

Answer (score -1):

timespec_add_safe is *in the kernel* (`grep timespec_add_safe /proc/kallsyms` should reveal this), not in any userland code, so even if you `#include` a file with the declaration, the definition is not present, so it will not link. The implementation is trivial. You could even cadge it from `time.c` in the linux kernel.
                    – Petesh